# SharePoint 2013 - Find when auditing was turned on for a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I have a site collection in SharePoint 2013 which has had auditing turned on. At present, we are auditing 'Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties'.

Is it possible to determine when this audit setting was turned on? Additionally, is it possible to determine which user enabled the setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audit log in SharePoint is used to record the history of events in the site.

It's actually a feature in SharePoint, we can't record when the specific feature is turned on and disabled.

According to my research, we don't have the tools to monitor the audit setting open time.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought that might be the case. I will leave this open for another day or so before accepting this as the answer though.